# Conditionally Access and Direct User in Django Class-Based View

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a Django custom form classed-based view. Under normal conditions I want it to be accessible to both authenticated and logged out or anonymous visitors. However, under certain conditions I'd like it to alert the user they need to login to submit the form (and redirect them). Example:

```
class CustomFormView(FormView):
     
    ...
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user 
        req_id = self.request.GET.get("req_id") 
        if req_id:
            errors = False
            if not user.is_authenticated():
                messages.error(self.request, "You must be logged in to fill out this form. Please sign in, then visit this link again.")
                errors = True 
                # redirect
            try:
                ... 
       
        if errors:
            ctx = self.get_context_data()
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)
```

I'm aware of `LoginRequiredMixin` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin)) as well as a decorator `@method_decorator(login_required)` but I don't want to apply it at the view level or to the entire `form_valid()` function, only check login state when `if req_id` condition is met. Currently the view's not executing my `if not user.is_authenticated():` so my attempt isn't correct. Is there a way to accomplish this within `form_valid()`? thanks

Comment: You write `self.request.GET.get("req_id")` implying `req_id` is a GET parameter? `form_valid` is normally called only for POST requests I don't suppose you send that GET parameter for the POST request?

Comment: yes req_id is a GET parameter that indicates if the form is a specific type of form the application needs to handle differently. req_id is used to look up a specific related object we need to pass information about and call save() on form submit